# EditText is not visible in Scrollview subview of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Relative-Layout in which there is a viewpager at bottom, and in view-pager adapter i have a relative-layout in which a vertical scrollview is added as subview. And there is a edittext in scrollview , so when i want to write anything in edittext then only scrolllview moves up not whole parent. Please provide me any suggestions.Thanks

[image]

after clicking on edittext "Answer" it is not visible-

[image]

in mainfest.xml - 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">

Comment: pl share your manifest

Comment: Are you able to scroll the whole layout? and what you want when you tap on your edit text?

Comment: No, when i am adding a simple edittext without scrollview then whole view is moving up. But with scrollview I can't see edittext, what i am typing in it.

Comment: Try: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I added a dialog with `editText` to type the text.

So when I click on that `editText` of `fragment`, I show that dialog with `editText` and move typed data in to `fragment's` `editText` click of dismiss/done/enter button.